# How can I change the name of an image when inserting it to the Android gallery?

Tags: android, image, image-gallery

When I take a picture with Android's camera app, it is inserted in the gallery with a name identical to it's creation date/time, like "2010-02-04 16.36.15.jpg"

In my app i take my own pics, and insert to the gallery them using
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
   ContentResolver cr, Bitmap source, String title, String description);

However, in the gallery they appear with a name that seems to be the time stamp of their creation in millis, like "1265323665851.jpg" , no matter what i put in the tittle argument.

I need them to have the same name they would get from Android's camera app, so that they will be properly ordered.

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question. I eventually found out the order of the pictures was about a field in the database.